# Git Merge Resolution Version Explanation

Tags: git, user-interface, merge

This is a simple question, or so I would have thought before trying to find the answer and as such please someone explain this to me.

When you fetch from remote and merge in the changes, when there are conflicts it informs you of such and that the files require merge resolution. (This is in Git GUI)

I know that of the files that are conflicting, I want the copies that I have done work on prior to the merge are the ones that I want. And can see them as follows.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
+  Code that I have added
  =======
+  Code that I replaced
 >>>>>>> origin/master
```

The question that I have is when I right click I get the options to:

- Use Remote Version
- Use Local Version

What I want to know is which direction of < or > applies to which version. As I have been in an instance which I had stashed some changes, done a fetch, then popped my changes and apparently my stashed changes became the remote version rather than the local version. And basically it's messing with my head and just want a crib sheet for knowing which option applies to which direction of angle brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words HEAD and origin/master answer your question.

The first block of code (after <<<<<) pertains to the HEAD (latest commit in local branch). The second block of code pertains to your remote branch.

The angled brackets always indicate which commit the code relates to.

Comment: So the <<<<<< Section is always the Local, while the >>>>> is always the remote?

Have had moments when the labels weren't always so clear cut

Comment: As far as I know it is not always the case. You should always check the respective commit and make sure you know which code is from where. The commits may be hashes but you can compare these against 'git log' of any branch you want.

Comment: Your indication is certainly reflected in what I see now. Thanks

Comment: @Struthious: "Local" (aka `--ours`) is in fact always `HEAD`. However, when rebasing, `HEAD` is the branch into which you are copying your own earlier commits, so that the "other" (various tools and programs call this "other", `--theirs`, or "remote") is actually your own commits (being copied by the rebase action).